# placing buttons on top of an image?

Tags: java, swing

So I'm struggling to get this to work. Trying to make a small tuning application. I want to place buttons on top of the appropriate tuning peg of the background image(the image is of a guitar headstock). However I can't figure out how to manage that with a flow layout. I may just be stupid but can someone talk me through whats going on here?

```
package guitartuner;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;


public class GuitarTuner extends JFrame{

private JFrame mainFrame;
private JLabel EJLabel, AJLabel, DJLabel, GJLabel, BJLabel, eJLabel, guitarJLabel,
        bassJLabel, loopJLabel;
private JPanel controlPanel;
private JButton EButton, AButton, DButton, GButton, BButton, eButton;

public class LoadImageApp extends Component{
    BufferedImage img;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public LoadImageApp(){
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/Yojimbo/NetBeansProjects/guitarTuner/src/guitartuner/headstock.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e){    
        }
    }
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
            return new Dimension(500,500);
        } else {
            return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        }
    }
}

public GuitarTuner(){
    createUserInterface();
}

public void createUserInterface(){



    JFrame f = new JFrame("Guitar Tuner");

    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    f.add(new LoadImageApp());
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    EButton = new JButton();
    EButton.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 10);
    EButton.setText("E");
    f.add(EButton);

    AButton = new JButton();
    AButton.setBounds(40, 40, 50, 10);
    AButton.setText("A");
    f.add(AButton);

    DButton = new JButton();
    DButton.setBounds(60, 60, 50, 10);
    DButton.setText("D");
    f.add(DButton);

    GButton = new JButton();
    GButton.setBounds(20, 100, 50, 10);
    GButton.setText("G");
    f.add(GButton);

    BButton = new JButton();
    BButton.setBounds(40, 100, 50, 10);
    BButton.setText("B");
    f.add(BButton);

    eButton = new JButton();
    eButton.setBounds(60, 100, 50, 10);
    eButton.setText("e");
    f.add(eButton);

    f.pack();
    f.setTitle("Aaron's Awesome Guitar Tuner");
    f.setSize (400, 575);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuitarTuner application = new GuitarTuner();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}   
}
```

Comment: SO is not here to talk you through your code.

Comment: I didn't mean literally... I mean more so why are my buttons refusing to be placed over my image. But if you want be rude and waste both your time and mine go ahead...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use GridBagLayout. Take time to read this. This may help you especially if you want to put the buttons on the position you want.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also add these lines at the beginning of your createUserInterface() - Method

**Edit:** You also have to remove the f.add(...) of your LoadImageApp-instance if you should do it this way.

```
public void createUserInterface() throws IOException {
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/Yojimbo/NetBeansProjects/guitarTuner/src/guitartuner/headstock.jpg"));
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Guitar Tuner");
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(){
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    };
    f.setContentPane(contentPane);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Components to overlapp each other you can use the JLayeredPane.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

You can put your LoadImageApp in one Layer and another JPanel with FlowLayout containing your Buttons in a Layer above that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dont extend `LoadImageApp` from component, extend it from `JPanel`
2. Override `paintComponent` method not `paint`.
3. Set layout of your new image panel from its constructor to `FlowLayout`.
4. Don't set your frame layout just add image panel to it. And add all of your buttons directly to the image panel.

Here is the working code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class GuitarTuner extends JFrame {

    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JLabel EJLabel, AJLabel, DJLabel, GJLabel, BJLabel, eJLabel, guitarJLabel, bassJLabel, loopJLabel;
    private JPanel controlPanel;
    private JButton EButton, AButton, DButton, GButton, BButton, eButton;

    public class LoadImageApp extends JPanel {
        BufferedImage img;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        }

        public LoadImageApp() {
            super(new FlowLayout());
            try {
                img = ImageIO
                        .read(new File("/Users/Yojimbo/NetBeansProjects/guitarTuner/src/guitartuner/headstock.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (img == null) {
                return new Dimension(500, 500);
            } else {
                return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
            }
        }
    }

    public GuitarTuner() {
        createUserInterface();
    }

    public void createUserInterface() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Guitar Tuner");

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        LoadImageApp panel = new LoadImageApp();
        f.add(panel);

        EButton = new JButton();
        EButton.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 10);
        EButton.setText("E");
        panel.add(EButton);

        AButton = new JButton();
        AButton.setBounds(40, 40, 50, 10);
        AButton.setText("A");
        panel.add(AButton);

        DButton = new JButton();
        DButton.setBounds(60, 60, 50, 10);
        DButton.setText("D");
        panel.add(DButton);

        GButton = new JButton();
        GButton.setBounds(20, 100, 50, 10);
        GButton.setText("G");
        panel.add(GButton);

        BButton = new JButton();
        BButton.setBounds(40, 100, 50, 10);
        BButton.setText("B");
        panel.add(BButton);

        eButton = new JButton();
        eButton.setBounds(60, 100, 50, 10);
        eButton.setText("e");
        panel.add(eButton);

        f.pack();
        f.setTitle("Aaron's Awesome Guitar Tuner");
        f.setSize(400, 575);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GuitarTuner application = new GuitarTuner();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```